# Pandas - Iterate through lists / dictionaries for calculations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to coding & I am looking for a pythonic way to implement the following code. Here is a sample dataframe with code:

```
np.random.seed(1111)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Product':np.random.choice( ['Prod 1','Prod 2','Prod 3', 'Prod 4','Prod 5','Prod 6','Box 1','Box 2','Box 3'], 10000),
'Transaction_Type': np.random.choice(['Produced','Transferred','Scrapped','Sold'], 10000),
'Quantity':np.random.randint(1,100, size=(10000)),
'Date':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2017','12/31/2018',  
                      freq='D'), 10000)})
idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

In the data set, each 'Box' ('Box 1', 'Box 2', etc.) is a raw material that corresponds to multiple products. For example, 'Box 1' is used for 'Prod 1' & 'Prod 2', 'Box 2' is used for 'Prod 3' & 'Prod 4', & 'Box 3' is used for 'Prod 5' & 'Prod 6'.

The data set I'm working with is much larger, but I have these data sets stored as lists, for example I have 'Box 1' = ['Prod 1', 'Prod 2', 'Prod 3']. If need be, I could store as a dictionary with a tuple like Box1 = {'Box 1':('Prod 1','Prod 2') - whatever is best.

For each grouping, I'm looking to calculate the total number of boxes used which is the sum of 'Produced' + 'Scrapped' inventory. To get this value, I'm currently doing a manual filter on a groupby of each product & filtering manually. You can see I'm manually writing a list of the products as a the second assign statement.

For example, to calculate how much of 'Box 1' to relieve from inventory, each month, you would sum the values of 'Box 1' that was produced & scrapped. Then, you would calculate the values of 'Prod 1' through 'Prod 3' (since they use 'Box 1') that were produced & scrapped & add them all together to get a total 'Box 1' used & scrapped for each time frame. Here's an example of what I'm currently doing:

```
box1 = ['Box 1','Prod 1','Prod 2']
df2[df2['Transaction_Type'].isin(['Produced','Scrapped'])].groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A' ),'Product','Transaction_Type']).agg({'Quantity':'sum'})\
    .unstack()\
    .loc[idx[:,box1],idx[:]]\
    .assign(Box_1 = lambda x: 'Box 1')\
    .assign(List_of_Products = lambda x: 'Box 1, Prod 1, Prod 2')\
    .reset_index()\
    .set_index(['Box_1','List_of_Products','Date','Product'])\
    .groupby(level=[0,1,2]).sum()\
```

I'd then have to do the same clunky manual same exercise for 'Box 2', etc.

Is there a more pythonic way? I would like to complete this analysis each month going forward. The actual data is much more complex with roughly 20 different 'Boxes' that have a varying number of products associated with each. I'm not sure if I should be looking to create a function or use a dictionary vs. lists, but would appreciate any help along the way. As a last request, I'd love to have the flexibility to write each of these 'Box_1' to a different excel worksheet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `idx` in your groupby code block?

Comment: Sorry - I use idx anytime I use .loc. I should have stated idx = pd.IndexSlice above. I've added that above now. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Can a `Prod X` use two `Box Y`?

Comment: @Ben.T yes. Basically any 'Box Z' will have multiple products assigned to it.

Comment: @keg5038 sorry my question was not clear enough. In your example, `Prod 2` uses `Box 1`, but could it also use `Box 2`? it is a bit different that " 'Box Z' will have multiple products assigned to it" if it make sense

Comment: @Ben.T sorry for the confusion - my fault! No, only 1 box will be used per product. Prod 2 would only use Box 1 & no other boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you want the result at the end, but as each `Prod` uses only one `Box`, then you can [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `Prod` by its `Box` and do the `groupby` like you do. Let's suppose you have a dictionary such as:

```
box_dict = {'Box 1': ('Prod 1', 'Prod 2'), 
            'Box 2': ('Prod 3', 'Prod 4'), 
            'Box 3': ('Prod 5', 'Prod 6')}
```

then you want to reverse it to get the `prod` as the key and the `box` as the value:

```
dict_prod = { prod:box for box, l_prod in box_dict.items() for prod in l_prod}
```

Now you can use `replace`:

```
print (df2[df2['Transaction_Type'].isin(['Produced','Scrapped'])]
          .replace({'Product':dict_prod}) #here to change the prod to the box used
          .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A' ),'Product','Transaction_Type'])['Quantity']
          .sum().unstack())
                    Quantity         
Transaction_Type   Produced Scrapped
Date       Product                  
2017-12-31 Box 1      20450    19152
           Box 2      20848    21145
           Box 3      22475    21518
2018-12-31 Box 1      19404    16964
           Box 2      21655    20753
           Box 3      21343    21576
```

Comment: Nice using dictionary with replace to capture more boxes. +1

Comment: Thanks Ben! This solution is very slick & great for the way my data is structured. I need to do some more testing, but this seems great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would filter my source dataframe down to just want I need to query first off then do you grouping and aggregrations:

```
df2.query('Transaction_Type in ["Produced","Scrapped"] and Product in ["Box 1","Prod 1","Prod 2"]')\
   .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='A'),'Product','Transaction_Type'])['Quantity'].sum()\
   .unstack().reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).agg({'Product':lambda x: ', '.join(x),'Produced':'sum','Scrapped':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
                          Product  Produced  Scrapped
Date                                                 
2017-12-31  Box 1, Prod 1, Prod 2     20450     19152
2018-12-31  Box 1, Prod 1, Prod 2     19404     16964
```

Comment: @keg5038 Ben. T solution is better and takes the extra step that I think you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why such a long expression is needed. It seems you only care about the total number of rows satisfying the condition, if I am not totally wrong.

```
d = {'Box 1': ('Box 1', 'Prod 1', 'Prod 2')}
d_type = {'Box 1': ('Produced', 'Scrapped')}
selected = df2[df2['Product'].isin(d['Box 1']) & df2['Transaction_Type'].isin(d_type['Box 1'])]
print(len(selected))
```

For your excel exporting needs, something as below would work.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx")
selected.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```